# Cannot launch iRobot Create. Powers down upon minimal launch?

Tags: ros, irobot-create

I just got an iRobot iCreate base and I've followed the instructions given in  ROS Tutorials to setup the turtlebot pc and the workstation. I could successfully ssh into username@turtlebot through workstation so I'm assuming that is all good. I had an issue with create not able to detect the usb cable which I solved using the detailed answer given for question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/46790/failed-to-open-port-devttyusb0/). This solved the problem of "Failed to open port /dev/ttyUSB0" that I was facing before.

Now the next step would be to ssh into the turtlebot (which I've done) and use `roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch` to do whatever the command does (I've no idea what to expect upon launch). But apparently something's amiss since the create base chirps and then powers down after showing `[kinect_breaker_enabler-5] process has finished cleanly` as output and the log file location (see output below), but I dont see a prompt. I checked the battery and that's charged so that's not the problem. **Following** is the terminal output.

```
anshul@AnshulsPC:~$ roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
... logging to /home/anshul/.ros/log/9d936a6a-fbdc-11e3-ba6b-00265e5f3bb9/roslaunch-AnshulsPC-5038.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://128.110.74.233:48495/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /cmd_vel_mux/yaml_cfg_file
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/digital_io/path
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/digital_io/startswith
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/digital_io/timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/digital_io/type
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/mode/path
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/mode/startswith
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/mode/timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/mode/type
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/nodes/contains
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/nodes/path
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/nodes/timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/nodes/type
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/path
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/startswith
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/type
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/path
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/startswith
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/type
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/base_path
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/pub_rate
 * /robot/name
 * /robot/type
 * /robot_description
 * /robot_pose_ekf/freq
 * /robot_pose_ekf/imu_used
 * /robot_pose_ekf/odom_used
 * /robot_pose_ekf/output_frame
 * /robot_pose_ekf/publish_tf
 * /robot_pose_ekf/sensor_timeout
 * /robot_pose_ekf/vo_used
 * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /turtlebot_laptop_battery/acpi_path
 * /turtlebot_node/bonus
 * /turtlebot_node/port
 * /turtlebot_node/update_rate
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    cmd_vel_mux (nodelet/nodelet)
    diagnostic_aggregator (diagnostic_aggregator/aggregator_node)
    kinect_breaker_enabler (create_node/kinect_breaker_enabler.py)
    mobile_base_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    robot_pose_ekf (robot_pose_ekf/robot_pose_ekf)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    turtlebot_laptop_battery (linux_hardware/laptop_battery.py)
    turtlebot_node (create_node/turtlebot_node.py)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [5055]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://128.110.74.233:11311

setting /run_id to 9d936a6a-fbdc-11e3-ba6b-00265e5f3bb9
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [5068]
started core service [/rosout]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [5081]
process[diagnostic_aggregator-3]: started with pid [5102]
process[turtlebot_node-4]: started with pid [5117]
process[kinect_breaker_enabler-5]: started with pid [5122]
process[robot_pose_ekf-6]: started with pid [5181]
process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-7]: started with pid [5226]
process[cmd_vel_mux-8]: started with pid [5245]
process[turtlebot_laptop_battery-9]: started with pid [5262]
[WARN] [WallTime: 1403641073.765412] Create : robot not connected yet, sci not available
[WARN] [WallTime: 1403641076.772764] Create : robot not connected yet, sci not available
[kinect_breaker_enabler-5] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/anshul/.ros/log/9d936a6a-fbdc-11e3-ba6b-00265e5f3bb9/kinect_breaker_enabler-5*.log
```

**Following** is the log file: /home/anshul/.ros/log/9d936a6a-fbdc-11e3-ba6b-00265e5f3bb9/kinect_breaker_enabler-5*.log output:

```
[rospy.client][INFO] 2014-06-24 14:20:12,442: init_node, name[/kinect_breaker_enabler], pid[5538]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2014-06-24 14:20:12,442: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0:0
[rospy.init][INFO] 2014-06-24 14:20:12,443: ROS Slave URI: [http://128.110.74.233:51362/]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2014-06-24 14:20:12,443: Started XML-RPC server [http://128.110.74.233:51362/]
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2014-06-24 14:20:12,443: _ready: http://128.110.74.233:51362/
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2014-06-24 14:20:12,444: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server
[rospy.registration][INFO] 2014-06-24 14:20:12,445: Registering with master node http://128.110.74.233:11311
[rospy.init][INFO] 2014-06-24 14:20:12,543: registered with master
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2014-06-24 14:20:12,544: initializing /rosout core topic
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2014-06-24 14:20:12,546: connected to core topic /rosout
[rospy.simtime][INFO] 2014-06-24 14:20:12,547: /use_sim_time is not set, will not subscribe to simulated time [/clock] topic
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2014-06-24 14:20:12,820: topic[/rosout] adding connection to [/rosout], count 0
[rospy.core][INFO] 2014-06-24 14:20:20,182: signal_shutdown [atexit]
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2014-06-24 14:20:20,187: topic[/rosout] removing connection to /rosout
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2014-06-24 14:20:20,188: atexit
```

From the logs, I could tell something told the create to power down. And since the log is named with 'kinect', I tried minimal.launch w/ and w/o kinect attached to the turtlebot pc. It doesn't make any difference.

Any clue what I might be missing? Or is this the way bringup works (I guess not)?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when using the Brown ROS Create drivers.  I never found the source of the issue but I did notice that if I powered the Create with a fresh set of AA's, using the Create AA-battery adapter, the problem occurred rarely if ever.  As the AA's charge ran down, the problem would occur more frequently.  It might be a silly and inefficient workaround but perhaps try it.  The AA battery adapter that I'm referring to is shown on page 9 of the Create manual (http://www.irobot.com/filelibrary/create/Create%20Manual_Final.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

To help people who may find this answer later, it's worth knowing that iRobot just published a guide to connect the Create 2 to ROS and a PrimeSensor; it can be found at http://www.irobotweb.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Create2_PrimeSense.pdf .

<sup>Please note that I am an iRobot employee, but the postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.</sup>